# Как повторять setInterval до определенного момента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

***Здравствуйте,***
Мне нужно повторить `setInterval` так, чтобы в условиях цифры `3`, `10` и `18` увеличивались на 19сек (`19000`). Я пробовал ставить туда переменные и в конце их увеличивал на 19 (`a = a + 19`), однако это не помогло. Скорее всего т.к. это `setInterval`.

Еще есть такие переменные как: 
 1. Количество повторений (`var newCurrentElement`) 
2. Время, после которого setInterval должен перестать работать и отчистить интервал (`var timeNewCurremtElement`)

```
function TextChanger() {
        counter = 0;

        clearInterval(timer);

        function TextChanger_Interval(){
            timer = setInterval(function() {
                counter++;

                if (counter <= 3) {
                    $('#in-hold-out').html("Inhale");

                } else if (counter <= 10) {
                    $('#in-hold-out').html("Hold");

                } else if (counter <= 18) {
                    $('#in-hold-out').html("Exhale");

                } else {
                    counter = 0;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }

            }, 1000);
        }


        TextChanger_Interval();

    }

    TextChanger();
```

***Заранее спасибо!***

Comment: я, если честно, ничего не понял. попробуйте объяснить саму задачу, а не то как вы ее пытались сделать. Вот есть у вас каике то вдох-задержка-выдох, вот про это и объясните, что вы хотите с этим делать

Comment: Смотрите, это техника дыхания для того, чтобы успокоиться и быстрее заснуть. 1 подход длится 19секунт: 4 секунды вдоха, 7 секунд задержка дыхания и последние 8 секунд - выдох. 

Также у пользователя есть выбор перед началом: от 1 минуты до 2х минут. За 1 минуту он проделает 3 цикла таких повторений. Обработчик для получения того, что пользователь выбрал у меня есть. Теперь проблема состоит в том, что у меня есть 1 текст, который я с помощью `setInterval` меняю. И он у меня меняется только 1 подход, а нужно чтобы столько, сколько и переменная `var newCurrentElement`. Ее я могу найти

Comment: проще и понятнее имхо другой подход - необходимо сформировать таймлайн - зависимость того, какой текст показывается на каком интервале времени и использовать эту информацию на основании того, сколько времени прошло от начала..

Comment: Изначально я пробовал использовать `setTimeout`, но потом я не мог приостановить этот процесс и я понял, что нужно использовать именно `setInterval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пользователь выбрал, например, 60 секунд и вы знаете, что подход длится 19 секунд, то:

```
limit = key * Math.floor(duration / key);

// 19 * (60 / 19) = 57, где `60/19` округлено в меньшую сторону.
```

То есть, на 57 секунде необходимо очистить таймер.

---

Для того, чтобы не прибавлять по 19 секунд на каждый последующий подход, воспользуйтесь остатком от деления:

```
current = counter % key;

// 44 % 19 = 6
```

То есть, данное значение счетчика 44 будет соответствовать 6 секунде вашей временной шкалы в рамках подхода, длительностью 19 секунд.

---

В процессе написания ответа несколько увлекся, получилось что-то страшное:

```js
// Интервалы, на которых необходимо
// сменить текстовую подсказку текущего действия.
const INTERVALS = [{
  time: 0,
  title: 'Вдох'
}, {
  time: 4,
  title: 'Задержка дыхания'
}, {
  time: 11,
  title: 'Выдох'
}, {
  time: 19,
  title: 'Упражнение окончено'
}];

// Пользовательские элементы интерфейса.
// Элемент для вывода подсказки.
const OUTPUT = document.getElementById('output');
// Продолжительность выполнения упражнения.
const DURATION = document.getElementById('duration');
// Кнопка для запуска таймера.
const TRIGGER = document.getElementById('trigger');
// Форма.
const FORM = document.getElementById('form_begin');

// Добавляем функцию обработчик для события.
FORM.addEventListener('submit', triggerHandler);

// Инициализировать и запустить класс,
// для изменяющий текстовых подсказок по временной шкале.
function triggerHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const hinter = new TimeLineChanger({
    intervals: INTERVALS,
    duration: parseInt(DURATION.value, 10)
  });

  hinter.on('run', function() {
      FORM.hidden = true;
    })
    .on('change', function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      OUTPUT.textContent = data.action.title;
    })
    .on('stop', function() {
      FORM.hidden = false;
    })
    .runTimer();
}

class TimeLineChanger {
  /**
   * Создать новый экземпляр.
   * @param {array} intervals Временные интервалы смены текущуго шага.
   * @param {number} duration Продолжительность выполнения упражнения.
   */
  constructor({
    intervals,
    duration
  }) {
    // Внутренние свойства.
    this._counter = 0;

    // Начальное состояние.
    this.action = null;
    this.timer = null;
    this.events = [];

    // Свойства, задаваемые аргументами.
    this.intervals = intervals;
    this.duration = duration;
  }

  /**
   * Добавление слушателя к событию.
   * @param  {string}   name     Событие.
   * @param  {Function} callback Обработчик события.
   * @return {self}
   */
  on(name, callback) {
    this.events.push({
      name: name,
      callback: callback
    });

    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Запустить обработчики, привязанные к событию.
   * @param  {string} name Событие.
   * @param  {object} data Данные передаваемые в обработчик.
   * @return {self}
   */
  fire(name, data) {
    this.events.map(function(item) {
      item.name === name && item.callback(data);
    });

    return this;
  }

  // Получить значение счетчика.
  get counter() {
    return this._counter;
  }

  // Установить значение для счетчика.
  set counter(val) {
    this._counter = val;

    this.timeIsOver() ? this.stopTimer() : this.updateStep();
  }

  /**
   * Получить ключ (временной метки),
   * указывающий на окончательное действие.
   * @return {number}
   */
  get stopedTime() {
    const [last] = this.intervals.slice(-1);

    return parseInt(last.time, 10);
  }

  /**
   * Получить метку окончания времени,
   * отведенного на упражнение.
   * @return {number}
   */
  get limit() {
    const duration = this.duration;
    const key = this.stopedTime;

    // `19 * (60 / 19)` === 57, где `60/19` округлено в меньшую сторону.
    return key * Math.floor(duration / key);
  }

  // Установить текущий шаг.
  set step(val) {
    const action = this.intervals.find(function(interval) {
      return val === interval.time;
    });

    if (action) {
      this.action = action;

      this.fire('change', {
        counter: this.counter,
        action: this.action
      });
    }
  }

  // Запустить таймер.
  runTimer() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    }, 1000);

    // Задать текущий шаг как начальный.
    this.step = 0;

    this.fire('run', {
      counter: this.counter
    });
  }

  // Остановить таймер.
  stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);

    // Задать текущий шаг как конечный.
    this.step = this.stopedTime;

    this.fire('stop', {
      counter: this.counter
    });
  }

  /**
   * Индикатор окончания времени,
   * отведенного на упражнение.
   * @returns {Boolean}
   */
  timeIsOver() {
    return this.counter >= this.limit;
  }

  // Обновить текущий шаг.
  updateStep() {
    this.step = this.counter % this.stopedTime;
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="output">Нажмите кнопку «Начать»</pre>

<form id="form_begin">
  <select id="duration">
    <option value="60">1 минута</option>
    <option value="120">2 минуты</option>
  </select>

  <button id="trigger" type="submit">Начать</button>
</form>
```